# O que significam os termos MDI e SDI em relação à interface de software?

Tags: terminologia, mdi, gui

O que significam os termos **MDI** (Multiple Document Interface) e **SDI** (Single Document Interfaces) em relação à interface de software? Li a respeito, porém estou confuso ainda sobre os termos, talvez por falta de exemplos. O que são esses padrões?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### O que são?

Os nomes já dizem tudo. MDI (*Multiple Document Interface*) se traduz para Interface de Múltiplos Documentos pois trata de uma escolha de método de interação em que um aplicativo permite ao utilizador manipular vários "documentos" em uma mesma sessão (uma mesma instância do aplicativo). Por outro lado, SDI (*Single Document Interface*) se traduz para Interface de Documento Único porque trata da escolha de método de interação em que o utilizador só pode manipular um único "documento" por vez (ou por cada instância do aplicativo).

Exemplo clássicos são os editores de texto. O Notepad, tradicional do Windows, por exemplo, só permite editar um arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por outro lado, o Notepad++ já permite editar vários deles ao mesmo tempo, selecionando o ativo a partir de abas (uma para cada arquivo aberto):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que eu utilizei anteriormente a palavra "documento" entre aspas. A razão é que o tal "documento" pode ser qualquer coisa além de um arquivo com texto. Um aplicativo de edição de música que utilize uma abordagem SDI permitiria que você editasse apenas uma música por vez, enquanto que outro utilizando a abordagem MDI permitira que você editasse várias, provavelmente alternando entre elas por meio de abas ou janelas internas. De fato, há vários padrões de design para aplicativos MDI, e as abas são apenas uma delas. Antigamente se utilizava mini-janelas internas na janela "pai" (a principal do aplicativo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas hoje é mais comum se utilizar abas ou janelas "dockaveis" (que podem ser "acopladas" em regiões pré-estabelecidas ou movidas para "flutuarem" como janelas independentes).

### Pra que servem?

Quando um projetista considera utilizar uma ou outra abordagem de interação, ele considera o uso que os usuários farão dos tais "documentos". A pergunta principal é:

> O usuário vai precisar manipular simultaneamente mais de um arquivo?

Se a resposta for sim, a opção por uma abordagem MDI pode ser a mais indicada. Digo *pode* porque nada impede você de permitir aos usuários abrirem mais de uma instância do mesmo aplicativo e editar cada "documento" em uma instância separada. Nesse caso, uma pergunta adicional importante é:

> Quais vão ser as interações entre "documentos" que o usuário precisará
>   fazer?

Porque se o usuário precisar interagir entre os documentos com bastante frequência (por exemplo, olhar algo que está em um para decidir como alterar o outro, ou copiar e colar, etc), pode fazer muito mais sentido do ponto de vista da usabilidade você fornecer uma interface MDI.

Comment: Ótima resposta, neste caso então o navegador de internet é MDI, e o Word é SDI, a finalidade da aplicação pode influenciar na escolha desses modelos de interface. Por exemplo, se eu criar um programa que permite abrir varias janelas, mas eu não consigo acessar as janelas anteriores até que eu feche minha janela atual, isso é SDI?

Comment: A maioria dos navegadores mais populares é sim MDI, mas podem haver alguns que não sejam. O Word, em sua versão atual, é SDI, mas já houve versões dele em que era MDI (a Microsoft alterou por algum motivo que eles julgaram importante). Não, o impedimento de acessar ou não janelas anteriores tem a ver com modo de abertura de uma janela (modal, por exemplo), e *nada a ver* com MDI/SDI. A ideia essencial que diferencia esses padrões é a manipulação simultânea de documentos.